# numpy is able to be imported in IDLE, but when I try to import it in sublime I get "no module named numpy"

Tags: python, numpy

I have tried force reinstalling numpy, and playing around in terminal. at first, I thought it was my build environment being python 2, so i updated it to python 3 but it is still giving me this error.

Comment: Is it possible you have more than one Python interpreter installed? This is nearly always the cause of this kind of issue.

Comment: how would I check that and fix it if that was the case?

Answer (score 0):

To check if both are using the same Python interpreter run this programme in both.

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

If the result is different, then that's your issue. You'll need to use the version of pip that's in the same location as the executable to install packages for that executable.

To do this, follow the path returned above and you'll find a subfolder called Scripts, in there is a pip executable. This executable installs packages for its interpreter only, so to install numpy for the interpreter you are using with Sublime, follow the path you got from sublime then use that version of pip to install numpy i.e. in terminal enter:

```
full/path/to/the/right/pip install numpy
```

Comment: when you say in both, you mean in IDLE and sublime?

Comment: Yes, you can also just type 'which python' into the terminal if you're on Linux or Mac to see which interpreter the terminal is using when you type 'python'

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: this is super elementary I know, but how do I follow the path? my output is: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 in sublime

Comment: If you want to browse there try this https://osxdaily.com/2011/08/31/go-to-folder-useful-mac-os-x-keyboard-shortcut/

Comment: Or in terminal you just type cd then the path